# How to create an ajax auto-refresh table?

Tags: 8, ajax

**My current situation:**

I have an entity list builder for my own custom entity type. I need to make this rendered table to refresh himself (the whole table) each X seconds (5 maybe).

**How could I achieve this?**

Comment: Could you define "better" in this context? What makes one method "better" than another?

Comment: Which makes the less time to get from the current situation to the required state.

Comment: Less time for whom?

Comment: The point I'm trying to get across is that "better" isn't definable, not within the bounds of this Q+A site at least. What's better for you isn't necessarily better for the next person, so this question isn't going to be intrinsically useful to other people. It's your job to decide which path you want to take, and this site will help you tackle any specific development issues you come across along the way

Comment: okey, I will change the question upon my preference of solution.